# Android Google Wallet Integration for transfer money person to person

Tags: android

Can we integrate Google wallet SDK for transfer money person to person. as i see in [google wallet](https://www.google.com/wallet/)  website you can easily transfer money person to person with google wallet App. but in my scenario i want integrate transfer money feature own app.